# Hard limits of Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f \in L^2$ be absolutely continuous on an open bounded set $(a,b)$.
Now, take $\phi_n \rightarrow f$ in the $L^2$, sense.

I would like to understand if we have the following limits.

1.) 
Let $p \in C(a,b)$ so not necessarily bounded at the interval ends. 
and $pf'\in L^2$. Does this mean that we have $$p\phi_n' \rightarrow pf'$$ in the $L^2$-sense?

Now the other way around:

2.)Assume we know that the limit of $p \phi_n'$ exists in the $L^2$ sense, does this mean that $p \phi'_n \rightarrow pf$ in the $L^2$-sense(which of course implies that $pf'\in L^2$ exists)?

My attempts:

1.) Maybe we have from the $\phi_n \rightarrow  f$ as $L^2$ convergence that a subsequence converges pointwise a.e. This could(I am not so sure) imply that $p \phi_n' \rightarrow pf'$ for a proper subsequence a.e. But I fail to see, how we can establish the $L^2$ convergence from this?

2.) By $\phi_n \rightarrow f$ we have that a subsequence $\phi_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise almost everywhere. Thus, we should also have $\phi_n' \rightarrow f'$ pointwise a.e for a subsequence. So we have pointwise a.e. convergence $p\phi_n' \rightarrow pf'$ and $p \phi_n'$ converges in the $L^2$ sense. So afais, both limits must be the same.

Could anyboy help me making this rigorous? One issue is that I am not sure, if we have $\phi_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise a.e. then the same holds true for the derivatives?

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: The primes like $\phi_n'$ are derivatives?

Comment: @GEdgar yes, they are

Comment: Then the answer is no.  $L^2$ convergence of functions does not imply convergence of the derivatives.